# Error while installing RPM -%post script of spec-failed dependencies /bin/sh

Tags: java, shell, rpm, rpm-spec

I am trying to build  RPM for my java code.RPM build and install sections works fine.But,later i have added a shell script in %post section to run shell script file that creates some files and starts the java application.The file gets copied fine.But, in %post section I get the failed dependencies bin/sh error.I am building the rpm on linux machine and target machines are centOS.I have also tried **AutoReqProv: no** in spec file.I am not running the install as a root user.also,target machines are not expected to have ANT(iam using it to build the java code-this might be not related to the problem) on them.I am attaching the code below.Default location of installation is in tmp folder.( for testing).

```
Summary: test           Summary: test
        Name: test
        Version: 1
        Release: 1
        License: Restricted
        Group: Applications/System
        BuildRoot: ~/rpm/BUILD/helloworld-root 
        URL: http://mycompany.net/helloworld.tar
        Vendor: Mycompany
        Packager: Mycompany  
        Prefix: /tmp
        BuildArchitectures: x86_64 

        %description
         Hello World

        %prep
        pwd
        %build
        pwd
        echo "changing directory"
        echo $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
        cd %{_sourcedir}
        pwd
        ant -f testbuild.xml
        %install
        pwd
        echo "in install"
        echo $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
        rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
        mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp/test/
        cd $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp/test/
        tar -xf %{_builddir}/test.tar

        %post
        sh /tmp/test/createdb.sh
        %clean
        %files 
        /tmp/test
        %changelog
```

i have also searched on google but couldn't find how to run shell script from spec.with oust post section, I have tried to run through command line it executes fine.I appreciate the help if  somebody can point where the problem is?

Comment: `AutReqProv: no` is [probably a mistake](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-tags.html#S3-RPM-INSIDE-AUTOREQPROV-TAG). Can you copy and paste the actual commands and error messages?

Comment: error is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959040/rpm-installation-fails-due-to-depencency-bin-sh-not-found.Except that iam not logged in as root and i get the error when i try to install the rpm.Now iam not using AutReqProv: no. THE SPEC file i am using is presented above. Is my %post section correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%post -p /bin/bash
```

That will give your post script a terminal to run bash commands and all that you are doing into it.